# discord.py add variable to command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to be able to type `?hoistable yes` or `?hoistable no` into the command to change variable of `self.hoist` to either `True or False`.

```
class ARB(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client
        self.hoist = True

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def hoistable(self, ctx):
        self.value = ''
        if self.hoist:
            self.value='yes'
        else:
            self.value='no'
        embed=discord.Embed(color=0x850000)
        embed.set_author(name="ARB", url='https://arb.bot')
        embed.add_field(name="hoistable", value=self.value, inline=False) 
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass it as the argument to the command

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def hoistable(self, ctx, value=None):
    if value is None:
        return await ctx.send(f'Use ?hoistable yes/no')

    if value == 'yes':
        self.hoist = True
    else:
        self.hoist = False

    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x850000)
    embed.set_author(name="ARB", url='https://arb.bot')
    embed.add_field(name="hoistable", value=value, inline=False) 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

To invoke

```
?hoistable yes/no
```

Comment: how do i make it if `?hoistable` is called without saying yes/no. it would give description that you need to type `?hoistable yes/no`

Comment: If the user doesn't pass the variable `MissingRequiredArgument` is raised, you can catch it with `isinstance` in the error handler and send a message, also this is off-topic to your question